# Total length of letters (A-Z) in String ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Scanner is printing me amount of each letter I get from inside of **List words = new ArrayList<>();**  which is 0, thats false.

The real amount of total letters in the **List words = new ArrayList<>();** should be what I write in the console and Enter it for the scanner to calculate the amount of letters.

My question is:
How I make a for/while loop that finds each letter in **List words = new ArrayList<>();**?

Here is my code:

```
package viikkotehtavat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;``
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lengthofwords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Syötä sana " + i + "/5: ");
            words.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        int sum = 0; 


        System.out.println("\nTotal amount of letters in the words are: " + sum);

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You never count the letters. You set `sum` equal to zero the line before you print it. Also are you are scanning in entire lines. What are considered letters? Are spaces letters?

Comment: yes but I dont want it to be zero, i want for the console to calculate it to me..yes spaces are also letters.

Comment: The **console** calculates nothing.  It only lets you get data from your keyboard into your program. Any calculating you want to do with that data you have to program for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
public class LetterCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Getting word " + (i + 1) + " out of 5");
        words.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    long count = words.stream().flatMapToInt(String::chars).count();
    System.out.println("total count is:: " + count);
    }

}
```

Comment: `var` is a keyword beginning Java 10 and is used for local type inference. If this does not work on your environment you can change it. The code though is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are inputting only words not sentences and wants a sum of total no. of letters combining all words, then this will help:

for (String word : words)
            sum+=word.length()-1;